Math Olympiad Problem - Fraction sequences
In basketball, we call the efficiency coefficient of a player the result of dividing the number of foul shots made by the number of foul shots taken. At the end of the first half,
Matthew's efficiency coefficient was less than
$3/4$, and at the end of the match, it was greater than $3/4$. ¿Can we asure that there was a time when its efficiency coefficient was exactly $3/4$? Answer the same question to $3/5$ instead of $3/4$.
Here is what I thought,
For $3/5$, there is a simple counterexample: Consider the sequence

$2/5$; $3/6$; $4/7$; $5/8$. First three fractions are less than $0.6$, and $5/8>0.6$. Clearly it is not true.

For $3/4$, I'm quite sure it is true, based on every example I've done. The thing is, if you achieve a number of the form:

$\frac{3k-1}{4k-1}$

You can't "score the following foul shot", otherwise you would achieve a coefficient of $3/4$. Then you miss the shot. Scoring the others, in orden to get close to $3/4$, the sequence goes like this:

$\frac{3k-1}{4k-1}$, $\frac{3k-1}{4k}$, $\frac{3k}{4k+1}$, $\frac{3k+1}{4k+2}$, $\frac{3(k+1)-1}{4(k+1)-1}$

And we end up in the same situation, because we can't sum. So I assume, thought this isn't a formal proof, that if we use some modular arithmetic argument around 4, we can prove that necessarily we achieve $3/4$.
Any help is welcomed.
Edit: This is from the Argentinian Math Olympiad (OMA), 2016.

I'm fairly sure that (in English) these are called free throws instead of foul shots :-)

The title is quite generic. Consider changing it to be more specific.

Apparently, free throw & foul shot are synonymous: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_throw. But the former is maybe more intuitive for basketball novices like me

As Shadow has mentioned, unless the title can be reworded to reflect the topic, at the very least, please mention the source of the Olympiad if possible. Otherwise, the current title is too generic to be useful.

For $3/5$, the sequence $(0/1,1/2, 2/3)$ gives a possibly-simpler counterexample.

Suppose it's possible for $3/4$. Consider a shot when it happens. Before it, the average is $\frac{m}{n}<\frac{3}{4}$, and after it, the average is $\frac{m+1}{n+1}>\frac{3}{4}$, where $m$ and $n$ are positive integers. Then $4m<3n$ and $4m+4>3n+3$, so $0<3n-4m<1$. But $3n-4m$ is an integer, so this is impossible. Note that the same argument would work for any fraction $a/b$ where $a=b-1$ and $a$ and $b$ are integers.

This is so cool... thank you very much. I didn't have any clue why for $3/4$ it was working and not for $3/5$. The idea of $a = b - 1$ is clarifying.

This is (a variation of) Putnam A1 from 2004 (see Kiran Kedlaya's Putnam archives).  There, the value is 80% (so 4/5) instead of 3/4 but the proof is the same.
Here is a geometrical proof.
Consider the non-negative integer points of the plane, where the $x$-axis corresponds to the number of misses and the $y$-axis corresponds to the number of successes.
After $n$ shots there will be $a_n$ success and $b_n$ fail, with of course $a_n+b_n=n$ for $n=0,1,2,\ldots$.  This gives a sequence of points representing the shots.  After $n$ shots the success rate is $b_n/(a_n+b_n)$
A success rate of 3/4 corresponds to 3 success for every 1 fail, equivalently, points on the line $y=3x$.  Points below this line have a success rate less than 3/4, points above it have a success rate greater than 3/4.
But the sequence $(a_n,b_n)$ happens on the integer points, and going from below the line to above the line , we must take a vertical step, and no such step can cross the line without landing directly on it. [note: to go from more than 3/4 to less than 3/4 corresponds to a horizontal step, and such a step can cross the line without landing on it]
The same proof shows that if we replace $3/4$ with $p/q$, then the answer will be yes if and only if $p=q-1$.

Thank you, is a pretty sorprising way of solving it.

Alternative approach:
Consider marginal approaches.
At the end of the first half, construe the score to be the number of shots made minus the number of shots that needed to be made for a $~75\%~$ accuracy.
The score is expressible as $~- \dfrac{k}{4}~$ where $~k \in \Bbb{Z^+}.~$
Thereafter, with each shot taken, one of two things will happen:

The shot will go in, which will raise the score by $~\dfrac{1}{4}.~$ 
This is because the player was supposed to only make $~3/4~$ of the shot, to shoot $~75\%~$ on that individual shot.  So $~1/4~$ of the shot is the overage.

Or the shot will miss, which will lower the score by $~\dfrac{3}{4}.$


The critical point here is that each individual increase in the score must be exactly $~\dfrac{1}{4}.~$
So, if you consider a score increase of $~\dfrac{1}{4}~$ as a positive step, you are forced to take such positive steps one at a time.
Therefore, if the score has gone from negative to positive, then there must have been a point when the score was $~0.~$

Now consider the identical question, with a $~60\%~$ shooting percentage.
So, the half-time score must be expressible as $~-\dfrac{k}{5} ~: ~k \in \Bbb{Z^+}.$
The critical difference here is that when you make the shot, the overage is $~\dfrac{2}{5},~$ rather than only $~\dfrac{1}{5}.~$
So, if you consider a score increase of $~\dfrac{1}{5}~$ as a positive step, you are forced to take such positive steps two at a time.
So, consider (for example) if you are $~4~$ for $~7.~$  Since $~4 - (7 \times .6) = - \dfrac{1}{5}~$ you are (in effect) down $~1~$ step.
If you then make the next shot, your score will go to $~+ \dfrac{1}{5},~$ meaning that you will have skipped over having a score of $~0.$

$\underline{\text{Addendum}}$
As pointed out in the answer of Alexander Burstein, the analysis applicable to the shooting percentage of $~\dfrac{3}{4},~$ will hold for any shooting percentage expressible as $~\dfrac{a-1}{a} ~: ~a \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 2}}.~$
In the parlance of my answer, this is because at half-time, you will have a score expressible as $~- \dfrac{k}{a} ~: ~k \in \Bbb{Z^+}.$
Then, each shot made will increase the score by $~\dfrac{1}{a}.~$
So, construing raising the score by $~\dfrac{1}{a}~$ as a positive step, you are forced to take such steps one at a time.

Thank you! It is great to have different proofs.
